# Форматировать отображение чисел в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице числа содержатся в поле с типом VARCHAR и некоторые записи вместо обычного формата выводятся через десятичную степень: 1.50935**E**6. При выгрузке в файл так и выводит через степень. Записей порядка 1к, как можно все исправить?

Comment: Создать новое поле, числового типа и переместить туда данные с преобразованием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неявное преобразование типа решает проблему:

```
select field*1 from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(field, 'E') 
     THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, 'E', 1) * POW(10, SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, 'E', -1))
     ELSE field
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '1.50935E6' AS field_exp,
       CAST('1.50935E6' AS DOUBLE) AS field_num
FROM tbl;
```